# Input size being disregarded and being set to 100% of parent element

Tags: css, flexbox

Input size seems to disregard the size attribute and instead set a width of 100% to the parent element.

Css:

```
.lespan {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: red;
  min-width: 300px;
  input {
    min-width: 0px;
    size: 5;
  }
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  size: 5;
}
```

html:

```
<span class="lespan">
  hello
  <input type="text">
</span>
<input type="text">
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/Lybvyz

I'd like both inputs to be of size 5.

Comment: Just add `align-items: flex-start;` to `.lespan`. Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmqwvY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing the wrong problem.
Stop using **invalid property values**. 
Size is attribute and attribute belong to HTML. [Set input size attribute with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134308/set-input-size-attribute-with-css)

Always inspect your code in browser.
If you want set size, then set the width of input.

```css
.lespan {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: red;
  min-width: 300px;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="lespan">
  hello
  <input type="text" >
</span>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

`size` is not a valid `css` atribute, but a `html` attribute. You may want to set them like so:

```
<input type="text" size="5">
```

Also, `display:flex` will break the size attribute value of the input, you might want to use `display:block`, use the css `width` attribute instead of `size` or change the html structue so that the input element is outside of a container with `display:flex`

Moreover, You can't nest styles, to apply a specific style to an element using both its tag name and a class name you might want to try something like this:

```
input.lespan {
    min-width: 0px;
    size: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `align-items: flex-start;` to `.lespan`. Here is the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmqwvY)

```css
.lespan {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: red;
  min-width: 300px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.lespan input {
  min-width: 0px;
  size: 5;
}

input {
  size: 5;
}
```

```html
<span class="lespan">
  hello
  <input type="text">
</span>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css width property:

```
input{
  width:200px;
  }
```

Or html

```
<input type="text" size="5">
```

Comment: Need to use min-width